# Convert encryption/decryption to its PHP equivalent

Tags: php, flash, encryption, actionscript, mcrypt

I am trying to convert the encryption/decryption program that was written in ActionScript and finding its PHP equivalent. The developer who wrote the action script code tells me that he used "TEA" algorithm to do it, but I no longer have contact with him. When I went searching for an equivalent TEA algorithm and run it, unfortunately the result that I get is different from the result from ActionScript. Can anyone help me in this please. Thanks in advance.

I have pasted the ActionScript codes here.

```
WIN_apiTEA.prototype.encrypt = function(src, key) {
          if(src.length == 0) return "";
          var v = this.charsToLongs(this.strToChars(src));
          var k = this.charsToLongs(this.hexToChars(key));
          var n = v.length;
          if (n % 2==1) v[n++] = 0;

          tempv = new Array(2);
          newv = new Array(v.length);
          for (i=0; i<v.length; i=i+2){
               tempv = this.mcrypt_encrypt(k,v,v[i+1]);
               newv[i] = tempv[0];
               newv[i+1] = tempv[1];
          }

          var encStr = this.charsToHex(this.longsToChars(newv));

          return [encStr];

     }

WIN_apiTEA.prototype.mcrypt_encrypt = function(k,y,z)
{
     sum = 0;
     while (sum != -957401312) {
          y = int(y + ((((z << 4) ^ (z >>> 5)) + z) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3])));
          sum = int(sum + 0x9E3779B9);
          z = int(z + ((((y << 4) ^ (y >>> 5)) + y) ^ (sum + k[(sum >>> 11) & 3])));
     }
     return [y,z];
}

WIN_apiTEA.prototype.hexToChars = function(hex) {
          var codes = [];
          var hexArr = hex.split("");
          var hl = hexArr.length/2;
          for(var i=0;i<hl;i++) {
               codes[i] = int("0x"+hexArr[i*2]+hexArr[(i*2)+1]);
          }
          return codes;
     }

WIN_apiTEA.prototype.charsToLongs = function(chars) {
     var tlength = Math.ceil(chars.length/4);
     var temp = [];
     var ti = 0;
     for(var i = 0; i<tlength; i++){
          ti = i*4;
          temp[i] = (((chars[ti] << 24) + (chars[ti+1]<<16)) + (chars[ti+2]<<8)) + chars[ti+3];
     }
     return temp;
}

WIN_apiTEA.prototype.longsToChars = function(longs) {
          var codes = [];
          var ll = longs.length;
          var x = 0;
          for(var i = 0; i<ll; i++) {
               codes[x++] = longs[i]>>>24 & 0xFF;
               codes[x++] = longs[i]>>>16 & 0xFF;
               codes[x++] = longs[i]>>>8 & 0xFF;
               codes[x++] = longs[i] & 0xFF;
          }
          return codes;
}

WIN_apiTEA.prototype.charsToStr = function(chars) {
          var temp = "";
          var cl = chars.length;
          for(var i = 0; i<cl; i++) {
               temp += chr(chars[i]);
          }
          return temp;
}

WIN_apiTEA.prototype.strToChars = function(src) {
     var codes = [];
     var strArr = src.split("");
     var sl = strArr.length;
     var cnt = 0;
     for(var i = 0; i<sl; i++) {
          codes[i] = ord(strArr[i]);
     }
     return codes;
}

WIN_apiTEA.prototype.changeKey = function(enctext, keytext){
          return (enctext.substr(0, 8) + keytext.substr(8, 24));
}
```

I started to convert it to PHP and this is what I have, however it isn't working (it gives me different encrypted strings than what I get when I run the original AS version):

```
class apiTea
{
public function encrypt($src, $key, $token)
{
    if (strlen($src) == 0) {
        return ("");
    }
    $_loc1 = $this->charsToLongs($this->strToChars($src));
    $_loc3 = $this->charsToLongs($this->hexToChars($key));
    $n     = count($_loc1);
    if ($n % 2 == 1) {
        $_loc1[$n++] = 0;
    }
    $tempv = array(
        2
    );
    $newv  = array(
        count($_loc1)
    );
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_loc1); $i = $i + 2) {
        $tempv       = $this->mcrypt_encrypt($_loc3, $_loc1[$i], $_loc1[$i + 1]);
        $newv[$i]    = $tempv[0];
        $newv[i + 1] = $tempv[1];
    }
    $encStr = $this->charsToHex($this->longsToChars($newv));
    return ($token . ':' . $encStr);
}
function mcrypt_encrypt($k, $y, $z)
{
    $_loc1 = $z;
    $_loc2 = $y;
    $_loc3 = $k;
    $sum   = 0;
    while ($sum != -957401312) {
        $_loc2 = (int) ($_loc2 + (($_loc1 << 4 ^ $_loc1 >> 5) + $_loc1 ^ $sum + $_loc3[$sum & 3]));
        $sum   = (int) ($sum + 2654435769.000000);
        $_loc1 = (int) ($_loc1 + (($_loc2 << 4 ^ $_loc2 >> 5) + $_loc2 ^ $sum + $_loc3[$sum >> 11 & 3]));
    }
    return (array(
        $_loc2,
        $_loc1
    ));
}
function mcrypt_decrypt($k, $y, $z)
{
    $_loc1 = $z;
    $_loc2 = $y;
    $_loc3 = $k;
    $sum   = -957401312;
    while ($sum) {
        $_loc1 = (int) ($_loc1 - (($_loc2 << 4 ^ $_loc2 >> 5) + $_loc2 ^ $sum + $_loc3[$sum >> 11 & 3]));
        $sum   = (int) ($sum - 2654435769.000000);
        $_loc2 = (int) ($_loc2 - (($_loc1 << 4 ^ $_loc1 >> 5) + $_loc1 ^ $sum + $_loc3[$sum & 3]));
    }
    return (array(
        $_loc2,
        $_loc1
    ));
}
function decrypt($src, $key)
{
    if (substr($src, 0, 1) == "<") {
        return ($src);
    } else {
        if (strlen($src) == 0) {
            return ("");
        }
        $_loc1 = $this->charsToLongs($this->hexToChars($src));
        $_loc3 = $this->charsToLongs($this->hexToChars($key));
        $tempv = array(
            2
        );
        $newv  = array(
            strlen($_loc1)
        );
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($_loc1); $i = $i + 2) {
            $tempv        = $this->mcrypt_decrypt($_loc3, $_loc1[$i], $_loc1[$i + 1]);
            $newv[$i]     = $tempv[0];
            $newv[$i + 1] = $tempv[1];
        }
        return ($this->charsToStr($this->longsToChars($newv)));
    }
}
function charsToHex($chars)
{
    $_loc2 = $chars;
    $temp  = (string) ("");
    $_loc3 = array(
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f"
    );
    for ($_loc1 = 0; $_loc1 < count($_loc2); $_loc1++) {
        $temp = $temp + ($_loc3[$_loc2[$_loc1] >> 4] + $_loc3[$_loc2[$_loc1] & 15]);
    }
    return ($temp);
}
function charsToLongs($chars)
{
    $_loc3   = $chars;
    $tlength = ceil(count($_loc3) / 4);
    $temp    = array();
    $_loc2   = 0;
    for ($_loc1 = 0; $_loc1 < $tlength; $_loc1++) {
        $_loc2        = $_loc1 * 4;
        $temp[$_loc1] = ((($_loc3[$_loc2] << 24) + ($_loc3[$_loc2 + 1] << 16)) + ($_loc3[$_loc2 + 2] << 8)) + $_loc3[$_loc2 + 3];
    }
    return ($temp);
}
function longsToChars($longs)
{
    $_loc2 = array();
    $ll    = count($longs);
    $_loc3 = 0;
    for ($_loc1 = 0; $_loc1 < $ll; $_loc1++) {
        $_loc2[$_loc3++] = $longs[$_loc1] >> 24 & 255;
        $_loc2[$_loc3++] = $longs[$_loc1] >> 16 & 255;
        $_loc2[$_loc3++] = $longs[$_loc1] >> 8 & 255;
        $_loc2[$_loc3++] = $longs[$_loc1] & 255;
    }
    return ($_loc2);
}
function hexToChars($hex)
{
    $chars = array();
    for ($i = (substr($hex, 0, 2) == "0x" ? 2 : 0); $i < strlen($hex); $i += 2) {
        array_push($chars, intval(substr($hex, $i, 2), 16));
    }
    return $chars;
}
function charsToStr($chars)
{
    $str = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($chars); $i++) {
        $str .= chr($chars[$i]);
    }
    return $str;
}
function strToChars($str)
{
    $chars = array();
    foreach (str_split($str) as $ord) {
        array_push($chars, ord($ord));
    }
    return $chars;
}
function changeKey($enctext, $keytext)
{
    // not needed yet
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AS3Crypto, you can find compatible solution with ASE-CBC in this case, look here:
[decrypt a as3crypto encrypted text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490903/decrypt-a-as3crypto-encrypted-text-in-php/19893191#19893191)